# Show that if $b\in\mathbb{N}$, then the set $\{b\}$ is primitive recursive.

Tags: logic, recursion

Question: Show that if $b\in\mathbb{N}$, then the set $\{b\}$ is primitive recursive.
Hint: The functions "addition", "multiplication", "subtraction", and the relations = and < are primitive recursive.

Definition. The set of primitive recursive functions is the smallest set containing the basic functions and closed under both composition and primitive
recursion.

I tried:
The set $\{b\}$ is primitive recursive if it's characteristic function $$X_{\{b\}}(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{rcl}
{1} & \mbox{if}
& x \in {\{b\} } \\ 0 & \mbox{otherwise} \\
\end{array}\right.$$ is primitive recursive.

$$X_{=}(x,y) = \left\{ \begin{array}{rcl}
{1} & \mbox{if}
& x = {y} \\ 0 & \mbox{otherwise} \\
\end{array}\right.$$ is primitive recursive.

$X_{\{b\}}(x)=X_{=}(x,y)$, so ${\{b\} }$ is primitive recursive.

Hints?

Comment: The final equation is not very clear...

Comment: It says: the characteristic function of {b} = the characteristic function of =.

Comment: May you use $\LaTeX$ to edit the post ? I think maybe my edition for yours is wrong. So sorry.

Comment: For $=$, it seems that you need two arguments: $x=y$

Comment: Thus, maybe: $\chi_{ \{ b \} } = \chi_{=}(x,b)$